# Is there an ID3 tag editor for iTunes on OS X?

Tags: macos, software-rec, itunes, id3

I'm looking for an iTunes ID3 tag editor for OS X.

I've tried a lot such as [iEatBrainz](http://jay.tuley.name/pages/software) and [PolluxApp](http://polluxapp.com/Home.html). Aside from the usual tagging, album artwork and lyrics are also important to me.  Most taggers I've tried haven't inserted lyrics reliably.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not free, but [**TuneUp**](http://www.tuneupmedia.com/) is a really good product.  Did wonders on my library, which had a ton of music that I took from podcasts (song of the day stuff).  Made it pretty simple to get the right album and meta-data as well as the album art.

> TuneUp is able to intelligently fix your music library using cutting-edge acoustic fingerprinting technology, which evaluates the song's digital DNA and references it against Gracenote's MusicID™, the world's largest database of music metadata.

Comment: yeah it works, but horribly. This program crashes 99% of the time, and the other 1% just sits there consuming about 20% of my CPU.. yes it works, but only open it when you need to do some cleaning.

Answer (score 2):

Check out [**Jaikoz Audio Tagger**](http://www.jthink.net/jaikoz/), it has full iTunes integration and it's available for Windows, Mac, and Linux. There is also [**Tune Up**](http://www.tuneupmedia.com/), the basic version is free but limited.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I've been on the hunt myself and haven't found anything as good as mp3tag for windows. So I've got that in virtualbox and playonmac (foss all the way).

Picard is nice in that you can add any fields you want (I often edit TCOP/WCOP/WOAF when releasing tracks under the creative commons) but I can't figure out how to change album art with it.

For a scriptable solution I've crawled back to the command line and have been using the free [eyed3](http://eyed3.nicfit.net/) which can be installed via macports

[id3 editor](http://www.pa-software.com/products/overview.php?prod=BC3B2E3A) is the fastest launching solution I've found but it costs money and doesn't have access to any custom fields.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I've always been pretty pleased with the crowd sourced information from MusicBrainz via their [Picard](http://musicbrainz.org/doc/PicardDownload) tagger.  I don't remember it supplying Lyrics and Artwork though so it may not be up to your requirements.

Comment: There is a plugin for Picard that fetches artwork from Amazon.