# Alternative to mp3tag for Mac OS X

Tags: macos, mp3, tags, sound-editing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is  a good .mp3/.m4v tag editor for OS X](https://superuser.com/questions/167513/what-is-a-good-mp3-m4v-tag-editor-for-os-x)

I like [mp3tag](http://mp3tag.de/) for Windows.

I've even written a post on my blog to showcase one of its powerful capabilities, that is, batching processing a given set of MP3 files allowing you to change any field of those MP3 files all at once. mp3tag has an action menu that gives you a lot of possibilities when it comes to editing MP3 metadata.

Basically what I'm trying to get is an app that have something like the replace action that I show in my blog post.

You can read my blog post here: [Mp3tag to batch process/edit MP3 tags](http://www.leniel.net/2010/05/mp3tag-to-batch-process-rename-mp3-tags.html)

Now I'd like to see if someone has come through a Mac OS X app that is as powerful as mp3tag.

Please share your findings.

**Edit 1:**

As far as I can tell, the only option that apparently does what I want in Mac OS is [Jaikoz](http://www.jthink.net/jaikoz/). It's not free.

**Edit 2:**

I just found that the Swiss Army knife Mp3tag can be used right within Mac OS. Take a look here:

[More MP3 guessing pattern with Mp3tag in Mac OS](http://www.leniel.net/2011/05/more-mp3-guessing-pattern-mp3tag-mac-os.html)

Comment: Also see [here](http://superuser.com/questions/50967/id3-updater-for-itunes).

Comment: Without paying, the best I've found is sadly iTunes.

Comment: @tobylane: iTunes can't do what I want.